# How to get the data source for the data points saved by Google Fit?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm trying to get the data inserted by Google Fit, but only the one that was actually recorded by the sensors and **not** inserted manually. I thought of checking the data source but it always returns null. Here's the code I used:

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();

Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest)
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataReadResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DataReadResult dataReadResult) {
                for (DataSet dataSet : dataReadResult.getDataSets()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Source: " + dataSet.getDataSource().getName());
                }

                for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Bucket: " + bucket.getActivity());
                    for (DataSet dataSet : bucket.getDataSets()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Bucket data type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
                        Log.i(TAG, "Bucket data source: " + dataSet.getDataSource().getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Is it possible to skip manually inserted data or even get the sensor that was used to get the data?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this one out?